# Store RASA chat history in local file system

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I am using **`RASA`** to create chat bot. I want to store the chat history as **`.txt`** file in local file system. I found that RASA support chat history storage for Mongo DB, Redis and SQL. However i want to store the chat history in local file system. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not supported out of the box by Rasa. You could however implement your own [custom tracker store](http://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/tracker-stores/#custom-tracker-store). 
I would actually recommend to use the [SQLTrackerStore](http://rasa.com/docs/rasa/api/tracker-stores/#sqltrackerstore) with [sqlite](https://www.sqlite.org/index.html). SQLite is also file based, which means you don't have to run anything in the background, but would probably be faster and less implementation effort than implementing your own tracker store. Note that the SQLTrackerStore is only supported since Rasa `1.0`.

Comment: @Ironman upvoted; your question is correct immo. Having a log file is an usual default allowing content retrieval with simple bash scripts, etc.
@Tobias I'm a bit perplex with using a database to store chat history. There are pros & cons. Using a DB help to manage history online, but requires to query the DB for everything :( What we need is maybe a `FileStore` ready done code example as starting point.

Comment: Have you tried using Rasa X to view conversation users had with your bot? It was built for learning from users' conversations and improve upon them. I think that makes more sense than to export potentially thousands of stories to a single file.